# get public data ex. location in profile page without access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, location, facebook-fql

Is there is way to get location ( city or country ,... ) for  specific  user. That  I can see in his profile page as public data - everyone can see that 
without getting permissions - getting his Access Token

Best Regards , 
Tmss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

I dont know whether its according to the facebook policies, but you can grab public fields with general access token (any valid access token)

See [this](http://zesty.ca/facebook/) .

Answer (score 0):

user/locale is accessible without a token, but that just gives you their language/country code.

user/location, the user’s current city, requires an access token.

Comment: Thanks CBroe 
just I have small question please about access token 
access token for the user or any valid access token will work  ? 

thank you again

Comment: The documentation clearly states what kind of access token is needed for what property – so please go & read it.